What is the easiest way to share a python environment?
So my goal is for a group of biologists to use a python library via the R language, because they only know this language. The library is scSpectra, that is not a really common library. There are some others libraries they need, like pyvis and rpy2.
There's an R library (reticulate) that allows the use of python scripts and libraries. The goal is for the biologists to install a python environment on their computer, and then use reticulate in R to call the scSpectra library.
I have issues with the installation of scSpectra on my computer, so I think that asking the biologists to install the libraries will not go well.
So what is the best way to easily share a python environment ?
I tried creating a python venv, but that's where things got wrong. Installing with pip rpy2 and pyvis gone well, but when I try to install scSpectra, something goes wrong whith the installation of numpy (scSpectra needs a specific range of versions). I didn't find how to solve the issue.
I then tried creating a conda environment, but I still got issues with downloading numpy, that I manage to solve this time. I don't know if I can share this environment in any way...
My last guess is to use docker, but I've never used it, so I don't know if it can be compatible with the "reticulate" R library.

You don't really share environments as a rule. Each of your coworkers/colleagues will create their own python environments. They will only need to install the same libraries. It is possible to create "requirements" files (may be slightly different depending on pip vs. conda) ... and anyway how these requirements files can list the libraries and versions to install and use these to reproduce the same environments on each machine.

A simple tentative could be to create a requirements.txt file with pip3.11 freeze > requirements.txt that can be installed with pip3.11 -r requirements.txt. So only that file would need to be distributed. Or python3.11 -m pip -r requirements.txt

What is the full list of all Python libraries (and versions, if these are important) that you need the users to install?

@TimurShtatland here is the full list :
numpy
json
scanpy
collections
scipy
pandas
matplotlib
scSpectra
anndata
seaborn
re
h5py
glob
statistics
math
typing

How do you use scSpectra from Python? That is, what is the import statement? I could not find any docs for it. I installed scspectra without issues, but import scspectra and import scSpectra both fail with the message such as this: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scspectra'.

@TimurShtatland yes you import it with import Spectra for some reason.

Use conda to install common bioinformatics (and many other) packages. For example, create a separate conda environment with a specific name (here, scspectra_plus), and install into this environment your libraries of choice using conda channels as listed in the order prioritized as listed from left to right (e.g., conda-forge prioritized above bioconda). This command needs to be executed once, to install the packages:
conda create -n scspectra_plus numpy scanpy scipy pandas matplotlib scSpectra anndata seaborn h5py -c conda-forge -c bioconda -c defaults

Activate this environment like so:
conda activate scspectra_plus

You can now use the libraries you installed into this environment. For example:
python -c 'import Spectra; print("ok")'

And deactivate this environment like so:
conda deactivate

Note: Several libraries (json, glob, math, re, statistics, typing) are parts of the Python standard library, and do not need to be installed.

what version of python are you using ?

@BlurKid Python 3.12.8. It is installed by conda into the newly created environment. Thus, typing which python prints this: /Users/user_name/miniconda3/envs/scspectra_plus/bin/python.

Ok thank you. It's downloading, so I will tell you later if it worked

Thanks, it worked that way ! So there's a difference between creating the environment directly with the packages, and installing the packages one by one later ?

@BlurKid There might be a difference, but I have not explored it. I listed all packages at once mostly for convenience. It is a good question, and it may be worth asking as a separate question on Stack Overflow (so as to attract more attention to it from the people who are experts on conda).
